Browser and CLI have Different php_pdo_pgsql Extension Versions
I seem to have a very weird issue where the version of my php_pdo_pgsql extension when used through CLI is different to the version used in the browser.
Current setup:
OS: Windows 11
PHP Version: 8.1.3 Thread Safe x64
Apache Version: 2.4.57
I'm not using a wamp / xampp installation. Apache is a standalone installation so I can swap PHP versions with somewhat relative ease :P
So when I run my PHP script in the browser I get the error
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above in C:\Repo\version_issue\index.php on line 2
PDOException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above in C:\Repo\version_issue\index.php on line 2
But when I run it through CLI it works O.o
Here's my test script:
<?php
$Database = new \PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=postgres;user=postgres;password=*******");

echo 'connected';
?>

Here's where it gets weird...
When I use phpinfo() in the browser my pdo_pgsql libpq version is 9.6.12.
When I use php -i in the CLI (command prompt) the version is 11.4.
I'm using the PDO php_pdo_pgsql extension that came packaged with PHP when I downloaded it.
And before you ask... yes, both CLI and browser (Apache) are using the same PHP version, and directory.
CLI PHP Config Path

CLI pdo_pgsql Version

phpinfo PHP Config Path

phpinfo pdo_pgsql Version

So, before I seriously start questioning my life choices, does anyone have any idea how, or why, this is even possible???
Googling only gives results for different PHP versions between browser and CLI, but nothing about different versions for an extension.

Is extension_dir set in your INI, and have you restarted the web process at least once?

Yup. extension_dir = "C:/PHP/php-ts-x64-8.1.3/ext". I've even restarted my pc ;)

My gut says it has to do with PATH. Can you run php -r "print_r(exec('which -a libpq.dll'));" and see where it points to, and check both web and CLI? The extension needs to be a specific folder, but the library might be able to be in other locations.

if you do just a blunt filesystem search, how many libpq.dll files it would find?

@NinjaScareCrow, is there any update on this? I'm legitimately curious about this.
